# How do we bind a date field to a "Value List" combobox with 2 columns?

Tags: ms-access, data-binding, combobox, date

How do we bind a date field to a combobox (with Row Source Type = Value List)?

We setup the combobox like this in the Form Load in VBA:

```
For i = 0 To 6
    Dim strValueMember As String
    Dim strDisplayMember As String
    strValueMember = format(DateAdd("d", 0 + i, anchorDate), "dd-MMM-yy") & ";"
    strDisplayMember = format(DateAdd("d", 0 + i, anchorDate), "ddd dd-MMM-yy") & ";"
    strItems = strItems & strValueMember & strDisplayMember

Next i
strItems = Left(strItems, Len(strItems) - 1)

Me.cboDeliveryDate.RowSource = strItems
```

This gives us a neat little combobox with the user able to pick from a list of 7 days. As a bonus he gets to see the day of the week (actually, for this end user, day name is quite important).

[image]

The combobox has two columns, a value column (for true date) and a display column (to show the day name).

---

But there are problems whichever **Bound Column** we set:

If we set the Bound Column to column **0**, it apparently works, but the value stored is 31/12/1899, 1/1/1900, 2/1/1900 etc. So it's just reading the combo's listindex and converting that to a date.

If we set the Bound Column to column **1**, it does actually work in that the selected value is written back to the database. But it is never displayed on the form, so the user *obviously won't feel that his edit has taken*

If we set the Bound Column to column **2**, we get a Not In List error.

---

All the above apply whether or not we use `dd-MMM-yy` for strValueMember or (as @HansUp answer suggests, `yyyy-m-d`).

Comment: Doesn't `Next intI` throw an error for you?

Comment: @HansUp sorry that was a typo in writing up the post here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like *cboDeliveryDate* has 2 columns, with *strValueMember* as the first and it is also the bound column, bound to a Date/Time field.  This worked for me by formatting *strValueMember* in a yyyy-m-d date format.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim anchorDate As Date
    Dim strValueMember As String
    Dim strDisplayMember As String
    Dim strItems As String

    anchorDate = Date

    For i = 0 To 6
        strValueMember = Format(DateAdd("d", i, anchorDate), _
            "yyyy-m-d") & ";"
        strDisplayMember = Format(DateAdd("d", i, anchorDate), _
            "ddd dd-MMM-yy") & ";"
        strItems = strItems & strValueMember & strDisplayMember
    Next i
    strItems = Left(strItems, Len(strItems) - 1)
    Me.cboDeliveryDate.RowSource = strItems
End Sub
```

I didn't know where *anchorDate* comes from, so I just substituted today's date.

Comment: i've copied your Form_Load into a a test Form1 and it's writing the correct date back to the database, however the selected value is never displayed back to the user

Comment: anchorDate, yep, today is fine

Comment: If I use 0";1" for the combo's Column Widths property, I see the same behavior as you --- the stored values aren't displayed in the combo as I move through the rows.  However, with any width greater than zero for the first column (even 0.1";1"), the stored values are displayed.  I don't know if that will be acceptable for you.  If not, see whether a callback function, as @iDevlop suggested, would allow the combo to operate as you want.

Comment: it seems that you've provided the solution in your comment - allow a very small amount of the ValueMember column to be displayed. it's not entirely satisfactory, but it's good enough. Many thanks.

Comment: Yeah, that's not ideal, but I'm willing to settle for "good enough" if you are.  I'd be interested to hear how iDevlop's suggestion would change this situation, but not interested enough to put in the effort to create a callback function.  If you are, please let us know how it turns out.

Comment: One final thought:  If you display the full width of the ValueMember column and format strDisplayMember as only "ddd" ... would that be acceptable?

Comment: formatting the dayname as a column in its own right is an excellent idea ... but do you know? in just 10 minutes of testing it i don't even notice anymore the vertical line signifying the first column with 0.1cm width. so i don't think the customer will give it a second thought

Answer (score 0):

While a bit complex, you can also create a function that returns the list of values you want.
See example [here](http://allenbrowne.com/func-02.html).